# Python dataframes - Finding the highest value from 2 or more different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just trying to figure out how to get the max() from 2 different rows in the same column.

For instance in my dataframe im trying to find the highest score from A and B, or A and C - how would I go about doing that? Also would like to learn how to find the max() from a range of rows (A to E) if someone could provid some insight.

```
    Date     | Class | High | Low
    2/1/2021 |   A    | 10   | 4
    2/1/2021 |   B    | 23   | 7
    2/1/2021 |   C    | 11   | 8
    2/1/2021 |   D    | 14   | 1
    2/1/2021 |   E    | 12   | 11
```

Cheers!

Comment: what is ur expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy output the actual highest value. sorry for not clarify!

Answer (score 1):

To find the max value in a row you can use [`argmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html)

```
>>>df['High'].argmax()
1
```

or

```
>>>df.High.values[0:4].max() # [0:4] is the range
23
```

or you can use a simple `if else` to compare two rows, for example:

```
if df.High.values[0]>df.High.values[1]:
    print(df.High.values[0])
else:
    print(df.High.values[1])
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help! just wonderiing if there was a way that i could also get it to calculate everyday. As in, everyday i get class A -> E results. So would it be possible to go Max of class A and C everyday?

Answer (score 0):

Actually went a different way for anyone who might need my solution.

```
a = df.loc[(df['Class'] == 'A') | (df['Class'] == 'B')]

abhigh = a.groupby(a['Date'], as_index=False)['High'].max()
```

Pretty much used .loc to create a database for all class labelled A and B
Then used group by to find the high score for each day.

I didnt clarify in my question but my dataframe has the class scores everyday so i needed a way to calculate the highet value for each day.